# Почему не удается обработать inline-запрос в бота telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, golang, telegram, бот

Нужно чтобы бот удаленно выполнял функции по вводимому тексту. Для этого попытался использовать inline-запросы. Код взял из примера:

```
func ChangedInlineKeyboardHandler(bot *tgbotapi.BotAPI, update tgbotapi.Update) {
    if update.InlineQuery != nil {
        query := update.InlineQuery.Query
        fmt.Println(query + "#################################################")
        data := "sdasdasdadas"
        callback := tgbotapi.NewCallback(update.InlineQuery.ID, data)
        if _, err := bot.Request(callback); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Сам бот был создан помощью BotFather, inline-запросы включены. Через update данные поступают и видно как меняется query-параметр с каждымм вводом символа. Однако обработка не проискодит.
Пример данных, которые приходят:

```
"inline_query":{"id":"number","from":{"id":number,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"user_name","username":"user_name","language_code":"ru"},"chat_type":"group","query":"ddsasdwas","offset":""}}]}
```

При этом, в самом приложении телеграма происходит следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. запрос отправляется, но ответа - нет. Почему так происходит? Как исправить этот код чтобы в результате inline-запроса возвращался текст?

Comment: Дебаггер показывает вызов panic. Выходит, что выбрана некорректная функция для ответа. А какая корректная - не понимаю. По документации на Inline-запрос должен быть Callback-ответ. Странно что при том не прерывается работа самой программы

Comment: Ошибка тоже не выводится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, этот код неверно написан.

1. Он использует `tgbotapi.NewCallback()` для создания объекта, который должен использоваться для обработки `CallbackQuery`, а не `InlineQuery`.
   Он использует `bot.Request()` для отправки ответа, который должен использоваться для обработки запросов от сервера, а не отправки ответа на inline-запрос.
2. Вместо этого вы должны использовать `tgbotapi.NewInlineQueryResultArticle()` или `tgbotapi.NewInlineQueryResultText()` для создания объекта с данными, а затем использовать `bot.AnswerInlineQuery()` для отправки ответа.

```
// create a inline query result
result := tgbotapi.NewInlineQueryResultArticle("1", "Hello", "world")
// create a inline query config
config := tgbotapi.InlineConfig{
    InlineQueryID: update.InlineQuery.ID,
    IsPersonal:    true,
    Results:       tgbotapi.Results{Results: []interface{}{result}},
}
// send the result
bot.AnswerInlineQuery(config)
```

Comment: Благодарю, ваш пример заработал на старой версии библиотеки. На последней почему-то полностью отсутствует функция  AnswerInlineQuery. Почему - пока не понял.